# how do I convert array into array of object along with id in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, data-conversion

let us suppose I have array

```
a = ["hello", "world"]
```

how do I convert it into

```
a = [
    { id : 1, value : "hello" },
    { id : 2, value : "world" } 
]
```

Comment: ```a.map((e, i) => ({
  id: (i + 1),
  value: e
}))```

Answer (score 3):

1. loop through the array using `map`. `map` returns a new array and applies to every item transformation
2. transform each item of `a` using the following rule `(str, index) => ({id: index + 1, value: str})`. `str` will take each item from `a`, and `index` will be it's index in `a`. returning new `Object` with properties `id: index + 1` and `value: str`

```js
var a = ["hello", "world"]

var b = a.map((str, index) => ({id: index + 1, value: str}))

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ["hello", "world"]; 

const convertArrayToObject = (arr) => {
 return arr.map((item,index) => {
    return {id :index+1 ,  value : item}
 })
}

console.log(convertArrayToObject(arr));
```

Here it is as a reusable function that you can use throughout whatever you're making.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```js
let a = ["hello", "world"] 

const b = a.map((item, idx) => ({
  id: idx + 1,
  value: item
}))

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **map** method:

```js
const a = ["hello", "world"];

const b = a.map((item, index) => {
  return { id: index + 1, value: item};
});
```